# javascript how to do permutations on objects

Tags: javascript, math, permutation, circular-permutations

I've got an array of 220 objects in javascript. Each object is of the form like this...

```
var foo = {
    foo: string
    bar: string
    i: number
}
```

I want to be able to find all permutations where (starting at the second item in the list) `bar == foo` and if the original `foo` appears again, it will act upon that. Permutation chains could be of any size up to the length of the list.

I took a quick through some permutations libraries but nothing stood out to me.

Any ideas for libraries to use to do this?

Thanks

Comment: So you have 220 objects which are `{ foo: string, bar: string, i: number }`? And are you checking if all the contents are equal to another objects content?

Comment: not equal...the only condition is that for the second element onwards element 2 foo must equal previous element bar. and if the original element 1 foo is seen again it is considered complete

Comment: well, then that isn't 220 objects, that's 1 object with 220 elements lol. And make a short example, because it's hard to visualise

Comment: right...its one array of 220 Json objects

Comment: I think I kind of get it now, but an example would definitely clear/clarify things

Comment: ill type one out on my computer